Finite Difference Method for simple continuity equation
I want to solve the simple transport equation
$$\frac{\partial p(r, t)}{\partial t} = \nabla_r \cdot \left( (r-r_0) p(r, t) \right) = \nabla_r p(r,t) \cdot (r-r_0) + n p(r,t),
$$
where $n$ is the spacial dimension.
This is a toy example and I think it's simple. I used central difference scheme for $\nabla_r p$ and explicit Euler method. When $t$ is small, it looks fine except that there is ripple. When $t$ grows larger, the sum of the density explodes. Why is this? I would really appreciate this if someone can give me some hint, or point me to some resources.
Please see the attached files for more details: code, density over time, density animation.

google "upwind differencing scheme"

@user619894 Thanks, it works!

Thanks @user619894 for referring "upwind scheme". Chatgpt gives the following code and it works.
# Finite difference scheme for convection
def update_density(p, vx, vy, dt, dx):
    # Upwind scheme for x-direction
    dpdt_x = np.where(vx > 0,
                      -vx * (p - np.roll(p, 1, axis=1)) / dx,  # Backward difference
                      -vx * (np.roll(p, -1, axis=1) - p) / dx) # Forward difference

    # Upwind scheme for y-direction
    dpdt_y = np.where(vy > 0,
                      -vy * (p - np.roll(p, 1, axis=0)) / dx,  # Backward difference
                      -vy * (np.roll(p, -1, axis=0) - p) / dx) # Forward difference

    # dpdt_x = vx * (np.roll(p, -1, axis=1) - np.roll(p, 1, axis=1)) / (2 * dx)
    # dpdt_y = vy * (np.roll(p, -1, axis=0) - np.roll(p, 1, axis=0)) / (2 * dx)
    dpdt = dpdt_x + dpdt_y + 2 * p
    return p + dt * dpdt

The new code becomes this. Also see the plotted animation and the sum of density. Interestingly, the sum of density gradually increases.

ChatGPT? How are you sure that this woorks?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@KurtG. I think the written code is the correct implementation of upwind scheme and I also tested it. I updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.

shouldnt the density be conserved?
